# render json serializer not returning json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

In our API, we are using ActiveModel Serializer to return json.

```
render json: { taxon: TaxonSerializer.new(taxon) }
```

What I'm getting back is

```
{
    "taxon": "#<TaxonSerializer:0x007ff704b6a820>"
}
```

What I'm expecting is

```
"taxon": {
    "name": "Test",
    "handle": "test"
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Maybe we aren't using the right version of ActiveModel Serializer?

This used to work but now, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: can you try doing `render :json => taxon_object, :serializer => TaxonSerializer`

Comment: it is like Subash said.

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your help. It worked previously but now it doesn't. We are rendering :json objects at many places in our code. If we had to specify a serializer, I must change more than a few hundred places which is fairly troublesome. Does anyone know why it doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue.
https://github.com/ohler55/oj/issues/199

gem 'oj', '~> 2.18.0' fixes the issue.